# Angularjs textarea ng-model object property each line

Tags: angularjs, textarea, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model, bindinglist

I am using angularjs and I am looking for solution to use textarea and ng-model two way binding between each line in textarea and specific property in array of objects.

For example:

The array will look like:

```
array = [{
    index: 1,
    value: "text line 1"
}, {
    index: 2,
    value: "text line 2"
}, {
    index: 3,
    value: "text line 3"
}]
```

And the textarea will look like:

```
text line 1
text line 2
text line 3
```

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Can you use separate inputs instead of a textarea?

```
<input ng-model="line-1">
<input ng-model="line-2">
<input ng-model="line-3">

{{line-1}}
{{line-2}}
{{line-3}}
```

---

Otherwise you will need to split the text based on return characters.

```
<textarea ng-model="myText"></textarea>
<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
    {{line}}
</div>
```

And add a watcher for changes in your controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.lines = [];
    $scope.$watch('myText', function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.lines = newValue.split('\n');
    });
});
```

You could also use a filter instead of a watcher but I think this will get you started.

---

When retrieving data from the db in your controller, you can reformat myText to be a string like so:

```
$scope.myText = db_array.map(function(obj){
    return obj.value;
});
```

This will create an array of:
`['text line 1', 'text line 2', 'text line 3']`

Then use join to convert to how you want it to be in the textarea:

`$scope.myText = $scope.myText.join('\n');`

Comment: Thank,
About the first option, I know that is an option.

Second option is a little problematic, because when I get the object from a database it get as array of objects, and I need to display it on screen and allow update it.

Comment: Can you use `array.map`? You can reformat the retrieved data to be a string.

Comment: I edited my answer to do what you are thinking. Honestly that is way more complication than you really need for a simple textarea. Why can't you store all the lines in the db as a single string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something simple like this, unless you prefer to create a directive

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.array = [{
    index: 1,
    value: "text line 1"
  }, {
    index: 2,
    value: "text line 2"
  }, {
    index: 3,
    value: "text line 3"
  }];

  $scope.getItems = function(){
    var items = "";
    $scope.array.forEach(function(item){
        items+=item.value+"\n";
    });
    return items;
  }
  $scope.deleteItem = function(item){
    var index = $scope.array.indexOf(item);    
    $scope.array.splice(index,1);
  };
}]);
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 50%;
  height: 5em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="MyController">
    <textarea>{{ getItems() }}</textarea>
    <div ng-repeat="item in array">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```